# Difference between view.hidden = x and [view setHidden:x]

Tags: iphone, view, show-hide

I'm debugging an iphone app and I'm seeing something I don't understand fully.

Based on user's selection, a UIView is being shown or hidden.  Current code shows or hides the view with `[view setHidden:NO]` and `[view setHidden:YES]`.  This doesn't work: visually it's as if these statements are simply ignored.  However when I changed these to `view.hidden = NO` and `view.hidden = YES` respectively, everything is working as expected.

I was thinking that the two syntaxes are equivalent, but apparently not.  For all other attributes (`text`, `font`, etc.), both work identically, so what's so special about `hidden`?

**EDIT:** Here's the copy/paste of some of my code.  I'm working in XCode 4.3 with iPhone simulator 5.0

Here's one example from my project.

```
IBOutlet UIView *panel;    //Connected in interface builder

===========

- (void)makePanelVisible:(BOOL)visible
{
    [panel setHidden:!visible];    //this does not work
    panel.hidden = !visible;       //this does work correctly.
}
```

Comment: There should be no differences, as setHidden is simply the setter generated for the property hidden. Actually, when you assign the property using view.hidden = YES, it should call setHidden internally. Can you paste some code, maybe the problem is elsewhere. Which type is your view?

Comment: There's not much code to paste.  The view is literally `UIView`.  I'll paste the two lines in question in a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking back about this, I remember running into the same issue almost 3 years ago, when iPhone 3 (not even 3G) was all the rage.  I'm not sure why this happens, but it does - so I just deal with it by setting the property using the "dot" notation.  I guess, this is one of those "don't fix it if it ain't broken" things (ok, it is sort of broken, but there's an easy way around it, so I'm using it).

Answer (score 0):

Sets whether the view is hidden.

```
- (void)setHidden:(BOOL)flag
```

Returns whether the receiver is marked as hidden.

```
- (BOOL)isHidden
```

hidden=YES; is identical to setHidden:YES; The difference is, you are turning hidden to YES right away Whereas sethidden view disappears from its window and does not receive input events because it is set to be hidden. It remains in its superview’s list of subviews, however, and participates in autoresizing as usual.

Comment: And how is this explaining the problem?  I know this already.

Comment: The issue is that calling `setHidden:NO` method does **not** hide the view - the view is still showing after the call; yet from all documentation, it should.

Comment: If the issue is set hidden: no method does not hide the view because it is set be no. set hidden:yes will hide the view

Comment: You definitely misunderstand my question: `[view setHidden:YES]` does not hide the view (although it should), but `view.hidden = YES` does.

Answer (score -1):

hidden is a property of UIView. When you wrote [panel setHidden:YES], you try to call the method setHidden that should set the property hidden. It doesn't work because the method doesn't exist in the UIView : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816

I always set the property by writing "view.hidden = x".

I hope it will help you

Comment: This is clearly wrong.  `hidden` is a property, which is declare as `@property(nonatomic, getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden`. This means that the owner class has methods `setHidden:(BOOL)` and `isHidden`.  If the method didn't exist, I would get an error or at least a warning in XCode.  Instead, the call seem to be simply ignored.